# Ada compilation issue (Looking for adbs I don't have?)

Tags: static, static-libraries, ada, gnat, data-distribution-service

I am trying to compile a third part library into my existing application using gnatmake..  And I am getting this error:

```
gnatmake: "dds.adb" not found
gnatmake: "dds-domainparticipant.adb" not found
gnatmake: "dds-domainparticipantfactory.adb" not found
gnatmake: "dds-publisher.adb" not found
gnatmake: "dds-topic.adb" not found
gnatmake: "dds-publisher_impl.adb" not found
gnatmake: "dds-datawriter_impl.adb" not found
gnatmake: "dds-domainparticipant_impl.adb" not found
gnatmake: "dds-readcondition_impl.adb" not found
gnatmake: "dds-datareader_impl.adb" not found
gnatmake: "dds-subscriber.adb" not found
gnatmake: "dds-condition.adb" not found
gnatmake: "dds-datareader.adb" not found
gnatmake: "dds-statuscondition.adb" not found
```

I added these to the gnatmake which builds the adp.  The -I contains all of the specs (.ads files), and the libnddsadad has all of the o files:

```
       -I/lib/ndds.4.5d/include/ndds/dds_ada \
       -I/lib/ndds.4.5d/include/ndds/dds_ada/support     \
       -I/lib/ndds.4.5d/include/ndds/dds_ada/support/low-level \

       /lib/Linux/ndds.4.5d/lib/GNATgcc/static/debug/libnddsadad.a \
```

Why does it want the actual body files?  Shouldn’t the specs + .a file be enough?  How can I circumvent this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specs and an archive library are not enough.  You need to specify the location of the .ali files.  Also, try using the -aI and -aL flags instead of -I.

Comment: See also [Source and library search path switches](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.3/gnat_ugn_unw/Switches-for-gnatmake.html#Switches-for-gnatmake)

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify:

[`-largs switches`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.3/gnat_ugn_unw/Mode-Switches-for-gnatmake.html#Mode-Switches-for-gnatmake): Linker switches, where `switches` is a list of switches that are valid switches for `gnatlink`.

[`-Ldir`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.3/gnat_ugn_unw/Switches-for-gnatmake.html#Switches-for-gnatmake): Add directory `dir` to the list of directories in which the linker will search for libraries.

For example,

```
-largs -L/lib/Linux/ndds.4.5d/lib/GNATgcc/static/debug -lnddsadad
```

Addendum: You might also look at

[`-Adir`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.3/gnat_ugn_unw/Switches-for-gnatmake.html#Switches-for-gnatmake): Equivalent to `-aLdir -aIdir`.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a gnat project file for the library, something like this:

```
project DDS_Lib is
   for Source_Dirs use ("/usr/include/dds_path");
   for Library_Name use "nddsadad";
   for Library_Dir use "/usr/lib/dds_path";
   for Library_ALI_Dir use "/usr/lib/dds_ali_path";
   for Externally_Built use "true";
end DDS_Lib;
```

and then in your project file, add `with "dds_lib.gpr";` at the beginning. You don't have to add anything to your Linker flags to link with this library, since it is done automagically.

Good Ada libraries already provide such a gpr file, which should get installed in the standard search path (for example /usr/lib/gnat/). If it is installed at a non-standard path, you can add the path to the `ADA_PROJECT_PATH` environment variable.

Comment: I have a similar issue as OP, but with a custom .a file I made myself, and have your solution building fine -- but when I try to add `with LibraryName;` to my code, the compiler is still looking for an .ads instead of an .a file. I'm trying to do this with a binary .a file where theoretically I don't have the .ali available. Is there a trick to getting this to work that I am missing?